# NestJS cannot resolve my UsersService dependency why? Is it due to UserModel?

Tags: nestjs

I am trying to learn NodeJS framework. I have initialized a project for that and now I am trying to add authentication to secure the HTTP access. I follows the NestJS documentation but I have the following error when I inject my UsersService in the AuthService:

[Nest] 14876   - 13/04/2020 à 09:26:19   [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?). Please make sure that the argument UserModel at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If UserModel is a provider, is it part of the current AuthModule?
- If UserModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AuthModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing UserModel */ ]
  })
 +2ms
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?). Please make sure that the argument UserModel at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context.

It seems that it is due to the following injection in my UsersService :

constructor(@InjectModel('User') private readonly UserModel: Model) {}

but I doesn't know how to solve this problem. My training project is stored on github :

https://github.com/afontange/nest-js.git

I read other tickets on same subject but I don't know what is the solution for my problem.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const UsersSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
});


Module({
   imports: [
   MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Users', schema: UsersSchema }]) // add
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
  exports: []
```

})
   export class AuthModule {}

Do you add in your Auth.module.ts

Comment: Thanks for all the answers but I received on github the following comment : Remediation
Upgrade minimist to version 0.2.1 or later. For example:

"dependencies": {
  "minimist": ">=0.2.1"
}
or…
"devDependencies": {
  "minimist": ">=0.2.1"
} I have upgraded minimist library and all seems OK now. I don't understant why this librairy is not installed by default by NestJS installer when you create a new project.

Answer (score 0):

The AuthModule is the following:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';
import { UsersService } from '../users/users.service';

@Module({
  imports: [UsersModule, PassportModule],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, UsersService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```